# Compact but non-bounded space?

Tags: general-topology, compactness, topological-groups

Does there exist *topological* spaces (in general) that are compact, but non-bounded?

I know that all compact sets are bounded in a metric space, but I was wondering if there exist some exotic topological space where this is not the case?

Cheers.

Comment: How are you defining *bounded* in general topological spaces?

Comment: If a topology isn't defined by a metric what do you mean by "bounded"?

Comment: I'm not sure if such a concept exists. I guess I should have been clearer - my question implies that there is a generalization of "boundedness" beyond that of metric spaces!

Comment: @Henry1981: There really isn’t a natural generalization of boundedness to topological spaces in general. It is possible to define a notion of total boundedness for uniform spaces.

Comment: You can take a look at [Wikipedia: Bornological spaces](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bornological_space).

Comment: Cool, thanks alot